# error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to URI

Tags: java, string, uri, jbutton, desktop

Im building a calculator with a hyperlink on a JButton to a website but im getting the error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to URI.

the error is in the line:

```
if(e.getSource()==LOGO
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse("Example.com");
```

What does the error mean? and how can i solve it?

```
/**
 Case : Computer Science Corporation
 */
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CSC extends JFrame {
    // frame settings//
    public static void main(String args[] ) {
        JFrame frame = new CSC();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Rekenmachine");
        JPanel Paneel = new Paneel();
        frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
//paneel opbouw//
class Paneel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public JButton Een,Twee,Drie,Vier,Vijf,Zes,Zeven,Acht,Negen,Nul,C,Min,Plus,Deel,Vermenigvuldig,Totaal,LOGO;
    public JTextField Output;
    static double a=0,b=0,result=0;
    static int operator=0;

    public Paneel(){
        setLayout (null);

        Een = new JButton("1");
        Een.setBounds(20, 225, 50, 50);
        Een.addActionListener(this);

        Twee = new JButton("2");
        Twee.setBounds(80, 225, 50, 50);
        Twee.addActionListener(this);

        Drie = new JButton("3");
        Drie.setBounds(140, 225, 50, 50);
        Drie.addActionListener(this);

        Vier = new JButton("4");
        Vier.setBounds(20, 165, 50, 50);
        Vier.addActionListener(this);

        Vijf = new JButton("5");
        Vijf.setBounds(80, 165, 50, 50);
        Vijf.addActionListener(this);

        Zes = new JButton("6");
        Zes.setBounds(140, 165, 50, 50);
        Zes.addActionListener(this);

        Zeven = new JButton("7");
        Zeven.setBounds(20, 105, 50, 50);
        Zeven.addActionListener(this);

        Acht = new JButton("8");
        Acht.setBounds(80, 105, 50, 50);
        Acht.addActionListener(this);

        Negen = new JButton("9");
        Negen.setBounds(140, 105, 50, 50);
        Negen.addActionListener(this);

        Nul = new JButton("0");
        Nul.setBounds(20, 285, 50, 50);
        Nul.addActionListener(this);

        C = new JButton("C");
        C.setBounds(80, 285, 50, 50);
        C.addActionListener(this);

        Min = new JButton("-");
        Min.setBounds(200, 285, 50, 50);
        Min.addActionListener(this);

        Plus = new JButton("+");
        Plus.setBounds(200, 225, 50, 50);
        Plus.addActionListener(this);

        Deel = new JButton("/");
        Deel.setBounds(200, 105, 50, 50);
        Deel.addActionListener(this);

        Vermenigvuldig = new JButton("*");
        Vermenigvuldig.setBounds(200, 165, 50, 50);
        Vermenigvuldig.addActionListener(this);

        Totaal = new JButton("=");
        Totaal.setBounds(140, 285, 50, 50);
        Totaal.addActionListener (this);

        Output = new JTextField("");
        Output.setBounds(20, 20, 230, 75);
        Output.setEditable(false);
        Output.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        LOGO = new JButton ("LOGO");
        LOGO.setBounds (20,345,230,75);
        LOGO.addActionListener (this);



        add (Een);
        add (Twee);
        add (Drie);
        add (Vier);
        add (Vijf);
        add (Zes);
        add (Zeven);
        add (Acht);
        add (Negen);
        add (Nul);
        add (C);
        add (Min);
        add (Plus);
        add (Vermenigvuldig);
        add (Totaal);
        add (Deel);
        add (Output);
        add (LOGO);
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if(e.getSource()==LOGO)
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse("example.com");

        if(e.getSource()==Een)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("1"));

        if(e.getSource()==Twee)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("2"));

        if(e.getSource()==Drie)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("3"));

        if(e.getSource()==Vier)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("4"));

        if(e.getSource()==Vijf)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("5"));

        if(e.getSource()==Zes)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("6"));

        if(e.getSource()==Zeven)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("7"));

        if(e.getSource()==Acht)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("8"));

        if(e.getSource()==Negen)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("9"));

        if(e.getSource()==Nul)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("0"));

        if(e.getSource()==Plus)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=1;
            Output.setText("");
        } 

        if(e.getSource()==Min)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=2;
            Output.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==Vermenigvuldig)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=3;
            Output.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==Deel)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=4;
            Output.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==Totaal)
        {
            b=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());

            switch(operator)
            {
                case 1: result=a+b;
                    break;

                case 2: result=a-b;
                    break;

                case 3: result=a*b;
                    break;

                case 4: result=a/b;
                    break;

                default: result=0;
            }

            Output.setText(""+result);
        }

        if(e.getSource()==C)
            Output.setText("");

    }
}
```

Update:

2 new errors have come up:
error: unreported exception URISyntaxException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
/**
 Case : Computer Science Corporation
 */
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.io.IOException;


public class CSC extends JFrame {
    // frame settings//
    public static void main(String args[] ) {
        JFrame frame = new CSC();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Rekenmachine");
        JPanel Paneel = new Paneel();
        frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
//paneel opbouw//
class Paneel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public JButton Een,Twee,Drie,Vier,Vijf,Zes,Zeven,Acht,Negen,Nul,C,Min,Plus,Deel,Vermenigvuldig,Totaal,LOGO;
    public JTextField Output;
    static double a=0,b=0,result=0;
    static int operator=0;

    public Paneel(){
        setLayout (null);

        Een = new JButton("1");
        Een.setBounds(20, 225, 50, 50);
        Een.addActionListener(this);

        Twee = new JButton("2");
        Twee.setBounds(80, 225, 50, 50);
        Twee.addActionListener(this);

        Drie = new JButton("3");
        Drie.setBounds(140, 225, 50, 50);
        Drie.addActionListener(this);

        Vier = new JButton("4");
        Vier.setBounds(20, 165, 50, 50);
        Vier.addActionListener(this);

        Vijf = new JButton("5");
        Vijf.setBounds(80, 165, 50, 50);
        Vijf.addActionListener(this);

        Zes = new JButton("6");
        Zes.setBounds(140, 165, 50, 50);
        Zes.addActionListener(this);

        Zeven = new JButton("7");
        Zeven.setBounds(20, 105, 50, 50);
        Zeven.addActionListener(this);

        Acht = new JButton("8");
        Acht.setBounds(80, 105, 50, 50);
        Acht.addActionListener(this);

        Negen = new JButton("9");
        Negen.setBounds(140, 105, 50, 50);
        Negen.addActionListener(this);

        Nul = new JButton("0");
        Nul.setBounds(20, 285, 50, 50);
        Nul.addActionListener(this);

        C = new JButton("C");
        C.setBounds(80, 285, 50, 50);
        C.addActionListener(this);

        Min = new JButton("-");
        Min.setBounds(200, 285, 50, 50);
        Min.addActionListener(this);

        Plus = new JButton("+");
        Plus.setBounds(200, 225, 50, 50);
        Plus.addActionListener(this);

        Deel = new JButton("/");
        Deel.setBounds(200, 105, 50, 50);
        Deel.addActionListener(this);

        Vermenigvuldig = new JButton("*");
        Vermenigvuldig.setBounds(200, 165, 50, 50);
        Vermenigvuldig.addActionListener(this);

        Totaal = new JButton("=");
        Totaal.setBounds(140, 285, 50, 50);
        Totaal.addActionListener (this);

        Output = new JTextField("");
        Output.setBounds(20, 20, 230, 75);
        Output.setEditable(false);
        Output.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        LOGO = new JButton ("LOGO");
        LOGO.setBounds (20,345,230,75);
        LOGO.addActionListener (this);



        add (Een);
        add (Twee);
        add (Drie);
        add (Vier);
        add (Vijf);
        add (Zes);
        add (Zeven);
        add (Acht);
        add (Negen);
        add (Nul);
        add (C);
        add (Min);
        add (Plus);
        add (Vermenigvuldig);
        add (Totaal);
        add (Deel);
        add (Output);
        add (LOGO);
    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if(e.getSource()==LOGO)
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("http://www.google.com"));

        if(e.getSource()==Een)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("1"));

        if(e.getSource()==Twee)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("2"));

        if(e.getSource()==Drie)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("3"));

        if(e.getSource()==Vier)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("4"));

        if(e.getSource()==Vijf)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("5"));

        if(e.getSource()==Zes)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("6"));

        if(e.getSource()==Zeven)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("7"));

        if(e.getSource()==Acht)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("8"));

        if(e.getSource()==Negen)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("9"));

        if(e.getSource()==Nul)
            Output.setText(Output.getText().concat("0"));

        if(e.getSource()==Plus)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=1;
            Output.setText("");
        } 

        if(e.getSource()==Min)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=2;
            Output.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==Vermenigvuldig)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=3;
            Output.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==Deel)
        {
            a=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());
            operator=4;
            Output.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==Totaal)
        {
            b=Double.parseDouble(Output.getText());

            switch(operator)
            {
                case 1: result=a+b;
                    break;

                case 2: result=a-b;
                    break;

                case 3: result=a*b;
                    break;

                case 4: result=a/b;
                    break;

                default: result=0;
            }

            Output.setText(""+result);
        }

        if(e.getSource()==C)
            Output.setText("");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to URI. 
>   At line: java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse("Example.com");

It should be

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.new URI("http://www.google.com"));
```

From the doc

> public void browse(URI uri)
>               throws IOException

**Parameters:**

> uri - the URI to be displayed in the user default browser

[Desktop#browse() reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI))

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) first. In the passing parameter you should use *absolute* `URI`.

> An absolute URI specifies a scheme; a URI that is not absolute is said to be relative.

[Desktop#browse(URI uri)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29)

> Launches the default browser to display a `URI`. If the default browser
>   is not able to handle the specified `URI`, the application registered
>   for handling `URI`s of the specified type is invoked. The application is
>   determined from the protocol and path of the`URI`, as defined by the
>   `URI` class.

```
try {
  URI uri = new URI("http://www.google.com");
  Desktop desktop = null;
  if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  }

  if (desktop != null)
    desktop.browse(uri);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException use) {
  use.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse()` function is expecting a URI as a parameter (read the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29)), and you are passing a String. change your code to this

`java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new java.net.URI("Example.com"));`

Comment: when changing the line the error changes from error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to URI  to error: cannot find symbol.   what is the symbol in the line?

Comment: @Nigelvandervalk see updated answer. you need to import `java.net.URI` or use the new line as it is

Comment: 2 new errors have come up: error: unreported exception URISyntaxException; must be caught or declared to be thrown error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. please help

Comment: you need to include it inside a try catch block.